# implementing a stack using a link-list in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, stack

I have written a code which will push a node into the stack, and i have implemented it using a singly link list. But whenever i run it, it shows run time error. Please help me out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    int key;
    node *next;
}*head=NULL;

void push(node *n){
   n->next=head->next;
   head->key=n->key;
   head->next=n;
   cout<<head->key<<" ";
}

int main(){
   node *x;

   cin>>x->key;
   push(x);

   return 0;
}
```

I am using C++ 4.9.2 (GCC-4.9.2)
Please help me out to find out where I am going wrong

Comment: UB, x does not point to anything.

Answer (score 0):

You repeatedly allocated memory *only for the pointer to the `node`*, NOT for the `node` itself:

1. Your declaration

```
    struct node{
        int key;
        node *next;
    }*head=NULL;
```

allocates only memory for the pointer `head` (and initializes it with value `NULL`).

Use this instead of it:

```
    struct node{
    int key;
    node *next;
    }some_node, *head=&some_node;    // Allocates memory for node and for pointer, too
```

2. Similarly, your declaration:

```
    node *x;
```

allocates only memory for the pointer `x`.

Use this instead:

```
    node other_node;             // Allocate memory for the struct node 
    node *x = &other_node;       // Allocate memory for the pointer and initialize it
```